# Block form of QR factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is simple. Given a matrix $M$ in the block form:

$$M=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B  \\
C & D  \end{array} \right)$$

where $A$ and $D$ are square. Is there an useful block form QR factorization of $M$? (such as:
$$M=Q\left( \begin{array}{cc}
A' & B'  \\
0 & D' \end{array} \right)$$

with a particular $Q$)

Comment: Are you sure to have in the LHS and in the RHS $D$?

Comment: Of course not :))